# How to read some contents of xml files and write them into a text file?

Tags: python, xml, text

I have a following xml file, I want to read the contents in `<seg>` and save them into a plain text file with Python. And I used the DOM module.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mteval>
  <tstset setid="default" srclang="any" trglang="TRGLANG" sysid="SYSID">
    <doc docid="ntpmt-dev-2000/even1k.cn.seg.txt">
      <seg id="1">therefore , can be obtained having excellent properties ( good stability and solubility of the balance of the crystal as a pharmaceutical compound is not possible to predict .</seg>
      <seg id="3">compound ( I ) are preferably crystalline , in particular , has good stability and solubility equilibrium and suitable for industrial prepared type A crystal is preferred .</seg>
      <seg id="4">method B included in the catalyst such as DMF , and the like in the presence of a compound of formula ( II ) with thionyl chloride or oxalyl chloride to give an acyl chloride , in the presence of a base of the acid chloride with alcohol ( IV ) ( O ) by reaction of esterification .</seg>
    </doc>
  </tstset>
</mteval>
```

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(r"path_to_xml file")
file = dom.documentElement
seg = dom.getElementsByTagName("seg")
for item in seg:
    sent = item.firstChild.data
    print(sent,sep='')

file = open(r'file.txt','w')
file.write(sent)
file.close()
```

while running above codes, it print all the lines on the screen successfully, but the file.txt only has one line of last `<seg>` (seg id=4), actually I want to save all the sentences into the file. Is there something wrong with my codes?

Comment: That's because you are only writing the last found item to the file. The writing to the file needs to also be within the loop.

Comment: As you said, I put the file writing commands into the loop and tried several times, but it was the same, always the last sentence.

Comment: You need to open the file for appending 'a' otherwise it overwrites the file with 'w'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only calling `file.write(sent)` once, open the file before the loop, and then add the following line to this code:

```
file = open(r'file.txt','w')

for item in seg:
    sent = item.firstChild.data
    print(sent,sep='')
    file.write(sent) // <---- this line

file.close()
```

Comment: According to your instruction, the problem has been solved, thank you!